# Prove that $\| \cdot \|_T$ is equivalent to $\| \cdot \|_X.$

Tags: proof-verification, normed-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism, equivalent-metrics

Let $(X, \| \cdot \|_X)$ and $(Y, \| \cdot \|_Y)$ be normed vector spaces and assume the map $T \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is an isomorphism. 
    Define A scalar-valued function $\|\cdot \|_T$ on $X$ by 
    $$\| x \|_T = \| T(x) \|_Y, x\in X$$
    Prove that $\|  \cdot \|_T$ is a norm on $X$ and show that it is equivalent to the original norm $\| \cdot \|_X.$

My attempt:

For all $x \in X$, $ \| x \|_T = \| T(x) \|_Y \geq 0$ because $\| \cdot \|_Y$ is a norm on $Y$.

Suppose that $\| x \|_T =0.$ By definition, we have $\| T(x) \|_Y = 0.$ Since $\| \cdot \|_Y$ is a norm on $Y$, we have $T(x) = 0.$ Since $T$ is linear and injective, we have $x = 0$.

$\|x + y\|_T = \|T(x+y) \|_Y = \|T(x) +T(y) \|_Y \leq \|T(x) \|_Y + \|T(y)\|_Y = \|x\|_T + \|y\|_T$

$\|\lambda x \|_T = \| T(\lambda x) \|_Y = |\lambda| \|T(x)\|_Y = |\lambda| \|x \|_T.$

Therefore, $\| \cdot \|_T$ is a norm.

Since $T$ is bounded, $\| T \|$ exists.

Therefore, for each $x \in X,$ we have $\| x \|_T = \| T(x) \|_Y \leq \| T \| \|x \|_X.$

As $T$ is an isomorphism, $T^{-1}$ is also bounded and hence $\| T^{-1} \|$ exists.

Therefore, $\| x \|_X = \| T^{-1}(T(x))\| \leq \| T^{-1} \| \| T(x) \|_Y = \|T^{-1} \| \| x \|_T.$
    Hence, $\| \cdot \|_T$ is equivalent to $\| \cdot \|_X.$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: "$\Vert x\rVert_T$ is a norm because $\rVert T(x)\rVert_Y$ is a norm (which map is a norm, *exactly*? $\lVert x\rVert_T$ and $\lVert Tx\rVert_Y$ are the same thing) and $T$ is linear": if $T$ is not injective, the map $x\mapsto \lVert Tx\rVert_Y$ is not a norm on $X$, because there are two vectors with norm zero.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: I corrected my proof.

Comment: You do not need injectivity to prove (as you did) that $\lVert 0\rVert_T=0$. You need it to prove that $\lVert x\rVert_T=0\implies x=0$; id est, to prove that there is no $x\in X$ such that $x\ne 0$ and $\lVert x\rVert_T=0$ (and I didn't see you do it).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: I have changed the proof. Do you see any problem now? Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: No problems now.